# Post dated Code Signature Apple

Tags: ios, timezone, unity-game-engine, app-store-connect

I made a game and it was uploaded last night on Apple platform.
I received an email with this :

```
 Post-dated Code Signature - Code signature identified by 'xxx.xxx.xxx' in bundle     
 'xxx.xxx.xxx' has a timestamp of '2013-09-22T10:08:32.000-07:00', but it was    
 submitted to the App Store at '2013-09-22T12:12:45.471-07:00'. This might     
 indicate that your system clock is not set to the correct timezone.    

If you would like to update your binary for this app, you can reject this binary    
from the Binary Details page in iTunes Connect. Note that rejecting your binary    
will remove your app from the review queue and the review process will start over    
from the beginning when you resubmit your binary.
```

Will this cause an app rejection later , or it will pass?
Because if it gets rejected, i would like to upload a new app with the "correct" timestamp.

Comment: anyone, got an idea ?

Comment: Was your app rejected? I found this post about this issue http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/100917/app-submission-response-post-dated-code-signature

Comment: No, the app was not rejected

Comment: You should the answer and accept it to get reputation from those who will find your answer helpful.